# Gremlins, water, and snow

Tags: gremlins

So in [Gremlins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlins) is a kind of creature called a mogwai.  Among the various rules is to not give him water, which would make him multiply and create the evil mogwai.

I only know about he the movie and its sequel, so I'm wondering if it was ever established somewhere else (Game? Book? Other?):  Why didn't the snow make them multiply?

We know they multiply while in Gremlin form because of the pool, but the snow didn't seem to do anything to the caroling Gremlins.  I would've expect body heat, if nothing else, to make the snow melt enough to act like the *single drop* of water that teacher used earlier in the movie...

Granted, come the second movie, they went rather crazy - a single camera flash reduced one Gremlin down to nothing but bones at one point.  Plus all the references and 4th-wall breaking.  So I won't complain if that movie is ignored for the sake of this question in regards to the first movie  ;)

Comment: Great question. On another note, this is one of those "What ifs": After watching his earlier short films, Steven Spielberg considered Tim Burton to direct the film. But decided against it because at the time Burton had never directed a full feature length film.

Comment: @WizardOz I think Burton should be given a second-chance at a remake....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would point out that during their chrysalis stage, the definitely mammalian mogwai transform into apparently reptilian gremlins.

Is it possible that gremlins are cold-blooded, or at least have very low body temperatures?  We never see any of them actually melting the snow, after all.

As far as I can recall, we also never see Gizmo get into the snow.

Comment: Yep, Gizmo was in the backpack for most of the movie.  He never had a chance to touch the snow.  And this doesn't even contradict the second movie!

Answer (score 1):

In the original script (which was significantly toned down and altered in terms of violence -- probably Spielberg's influence), it is specified that they cannot reproduced below 25 degrees. This was probably included for precisely this reason. It doesn't account for body heat melting the snow, but it's at least a basic rationale for why snow doesn't cause them to multiply.

Comment: You should add the part in the script this relates to in the answer.

Comment: 25 degrees Fahrenheit? Melting snow is 32 degrees isn't it?

Comment: @user14111: Generally, yes, unless there's a significant difference in salinity, pressure, or the chemical composition of the snow, it melts around 32 degrees Fahrenheit.  Given that 25 degrees Celcius is 77 F, I doubt they were using that scale, either.

Comment: @Jeff Maybe 25 was a typo for 35?